# Llamar a función desde un Thread c++

Tags: c++, hilos, visual-c++

Estoy trabajando en Visual studio c++.

Tengo un hilo que corre al mismo tiempo que el programa, básicamente es un timer, y al pasar 10 segundos tiene que llamar a una función para que apague la luz de una pantalla.

La llamada a la función lo hace bien pero no transmite el código para que se apague la pantalla.

Si en vez de llamar a la función desde el hilo lo llamo desde otro sitio la pantalla se apaga.

Puede ser que haya que hacer una llamada segura.

```
void FuncionLight(HANDLE portHandle,DWORD bytesTransmitted)//funcion que apaga la pantalla
{
      cout << "backoff";
      WriteFile(portHandle, backlight_off , 4, &bytesTransmitted, NULL);
}
```

---

```
DWORD WINAPI solo_thread(void* arg) //el hilo
{ 
   int Counter = 0;
   printf( "In second thread...\n" );

   while ( true )
   {
       if(Counter<10)
       {
           Counter++;
           Sleep(1000);
       }
       else 
       {
           printf( "Han pasado 10 segundos; Counter:-> %d\n", Counter );
           FuncionLight(portHandle,bytesTransmitted);
           Counter = 0;
       }

   }

   return 0;
}
```

Sigo con el mismo problema. Pero me he dado cuenta que si las comunicaiones RS232 las inicializo en el hilo o la funcion consigo que la pantalla se apague, pero entonces no puedo usar las comunicaiones en otro sitio que no sea el hilo o la funcion.

Comment: No. Estoy creando un thread que cuenta de 0 a 10. Cuendo llega a 10 llamo a una funcion para que se apague la pantalla. Una vez que se apaga empiezo a contar desde 0 para que cuando llegue a 10 se apague otra vez(ya que el usuario la habra encendido).

Comment: Lo que no comprendo es que cuando llamo a la funcion desde el thread la linea de writefile no se ejecuta o se ejecuta mal, y cuando llamo la funcion desde otra parte del programa si lo hace.

Comment: Quiza no te estoy entendiendo o quiza mi codigo no estaba bien estructurado. Lo he cambiado. Si consideras que el problema es el mismo avisame. Primero tengo la funcion de funcionlight y luego viene el thread WINAPI solo_thread. Gracias

Comment: Ok, había leído mal tu código. Ahora se ve mucho más claro.

Comment: portHandle y bytesTransmitted son dos variables globales? Como le llegan estas variables al thread? (veo que no usas el parámetro)

Comment: si son dos parametros globales, pero creo que el hilo esta creando algun conflicto...

Comment: he encontrado algo parecido aqui, simplemente quiero llamar a una funcion desde un thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818493/calling-and-executing-function-on-a-different-thread

Comment: Tu ejemplo es correcto y si son variables globales, el manejador también será válido. Sin mas datos, los consejos que te puedo dar son: utilizar un semáforo o hazte una [sección crítica](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms686908(v=vs.85).aspx) para que tan sólo un thread este escribiendo al mismo tiempo en el puerto. Independientemente a eso y según lo que estés haciendo en el proceso principal, considera utilizar [DuplicateHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: en el proceso principal tambien estoy escribiendo en el mismo puerto y cuando salta la funcion quizas este algun proceso de escritura abierto. Mirare los enlaces que me has dejado. Gracias!

Comment: @Andermutu una recomendación, no uses `Sleep();` si dependes de la exactitud del tiempo ya que es impreciso, usa un timer de otra forma.

Comment: No, la verdad que la exactitud del tiempo no me importa demasiado, pero gracias. Cuando tenga tiempo tratare de optimizarlo.

Comment: Deberías comprobar el valor devuelto por WriteFile, y si no fuera TRUE, ver qué dice GetLastError